# UICollectionViewController in iOS 8.1 won't allow custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, ios8.1

Is anyone having a problem with Xcode 6 when adding a Collection View Controller to storyboards and naming the custom class?

-> I drag a Collection View Controller to my scene -> add a new file -> name it "LCCollectionViewController" with a subclass of UICollectionViewController.

Next, I select the Collection View Controller in storyboard, and name the custom class LCCollectionViewController in the identity inspector.

Problem: The document outline still shows the name as Collection View Controller.

Code just in case:
LCCollectionViewController.m

```
@interface LCCollectionViewController ()
{
   NSArray *theImages;
}
@end

@implementation LCCollectionViewController

    static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

moonImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.gif", @"image2.gif", @"image3.gif", @"image4.gif", nil];
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [moonImages count];

}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell
UIImageView *theImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
theImageView.image = [theImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: I can't really remember much of objective-c now but aren't you supposed to specify that it is a subclass of UICollectionViewController? ( `@implementation LCCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController`)

Comment: it allows..! mention how to did you add new file.?

Comment: @lascort the subclass is in the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered same bug in xcode6. What helped me was to change subclass to any other viewcontroller subclass you have set up already (perhaps create temporary one if none is available) and then change it back to LLCollectionViewController.